# Add and remove active class

Tags: lit-element

I have a navbar contains some items. How to add an active class to the clicked item and remove from other items?
i have tried to get those elements by document.getElementsByClassName but it throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are talking about **LitElement** and [webcomponents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) most likely the component you are working on has a [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

So because of that querying the document is from the start a mistake, you want the lookup to happen inside your element, not in the top document level.

So inside one of your component, to get all the elements with a certain class instead of:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item')
```

you would do something like

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementsByClassName('item')
```

or

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.item')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by binding the `class` property using the [`classMap` directive](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#classmap). Per the docs `classMap`:

> Sets a list of classes based on an object. Each key in the object is treated as a class name, and if the value associated with the key is truthy, that class is added to the element.

For example, suppose you element has a `navItems` property like this:

```js
this.navItems = [
  { id: 'home', href: '/', title: 'Home' },
  { id: 'contact', href: '/contact', title: 'Contact Us' },
];
```

...and an `activeNavItemId` property corresponding to one of those `id`s. You could render them like this:

```js
import { classMap } from 'lit-html/directives/class-map';

// ...

render() {
  return html`
    <nav>
      <ul>
        ${this.navItems.map(item => html`
          <li class=${classMap({ active: this.activeNavItemId === item.id })}>
            <a href=${item.href}>${item.title}</a>
          </li>
        `)}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  `;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i just found this elegant solution and I'd really like to use it. I have installed lit-element and lit-html which seems to be interfering with each other. When I uninstall lit-html my application works again, but when I have both Webpack throws an error saying unsafeSVG is not exported from lit-html. Do you know how I should fix this?